# ServletContextListener not being called in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a ServletContextListener to fire in my app engine app:

```
package com.me.test;

public class WarmupListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.err.println("hi!");
        System.out.println("hi!");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "hi!");
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // App Engine does not currently invoke this method.
    }
}

// web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.me.test.WarmupListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

It's un unpaid app, not sure if that makes a difference. I see nothing in the app logs either after a publish, or after I try hitting an endpoint.

Is there something else I need to set to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure to have the good path to your class file?

Comment: Out of my experience System.out and System.err messages will appear on your local dev server, but not on App Engine logs, although I thought the logger.log should appear

Comment: Given the code you supplied, I can't reproduce. Could you upload a minimal reproducing example?